# Current Folder, Desktop folder Directory from SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server query is there a way to refrence Current Directory, Desktop or Current User folders?  I often export files and I am going to be migrating to a temporary server; upgrading and going back to original server.  Having these refrences would be helpful to cut down on my editing of queries and stored procedures.

Sending from Batch file isn't working errors out with Drive letter getting dropped.  ':\User\' Invalid Argument.

Comment: Are you looking  to change SQL server management studio default file save location?

Comment: I save files to Desktop folder, but user name will change due to different files.  I decided to reference through batch files.  Batch wise I know how to do it without changing queries, but would rather do it in SQL Query.  Just don't know how to find desktop in SQL Query.